# Python string interpolation using dictionary and strings

Tags: python, string, string-interpolation

Given:

```
dict = {"path": "/var/blah"}
curr = "1.1"
prev = "1.0"
```

What's the best/shortest way to interpolate the string to generate the following:

> path: /var/blah curr: 1.1 prev: 1.0

I know this works:

```
str = "path: %(path)s curr: %(curr)s prev: %(prev)s" % {"path": dict["path"],"curr": curr, "prev": prev}
```

But I was hoping there is a shorter way, such as:

```
str = "path: %(path)s curr: %s prev: %s" % (dict, curr, prev)
```

My apologies if this seems like an overly pedantic question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not:

```
mystr = "path: %s curr: %s prev: %s" % (mydict[path], curr, prev)
```

BTW, I've changed a couple names you were using that trample upon builtin names -- don't do that, it's never needed and once in a while will waste a lot of your time tracking down a misbehavior it causes (where something's using the builtin name assuming it means the builtin but you have hidden it with the name of our own variable).

Answer (score 59):

You can try this:

```
data = {"path": "/var/blah",
        "curr": "1.1",
        "prev": "1.0"}

s = "path: %(path)s curr: %(curr)s prev: %(prev)s" % data
```

Answer (score 29):

And of course you could use the newer (from 2.6) [**.format**](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) string method:

```
>>> mydict = {"path": "/var/blah"}
>>> curr = "1.1"
>>> prev = "1.0"
>>>
>>> s = "path: {0} curr: {1} prev: {2}".format(mydict['path'], curr, prev)
>>> s
'path: /var/blah curr: 1.1 prev: 1.0'
```

Or, if all elements were in the dictionary, you could do this:

```
>>> mydict = {"path": "/var/blah", "curr": 1.1, "prev": 1.0}
>>> "path: {path} curr: {curr} prev: {prev}".format(**mydict)
'path: /var/blah curr: 1.1 prev: 1.0'
>>>
```

From the [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) documentation:

> This method of string formatting is
>   the new standard in Python 3.0, and
>   should be preferred to the %
>   formatting described in [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#string-formatting) in new code.

Comment: Using str.format he could write `"path: {mydict[path]} curr: {curr} prev: {prev}".format(mydict=mydict, curr=curr, prev=prev)` or even `locals()` for the argument to format, `"path: {mydict[path]} curr: {curr} prev: {prev}".format(**locals())`

Answer (score 13):

Maybe:

```
path = dict['path']
str = "path: %(path)s curr: %(curr)s prev: %(prev)s" % locals()
```

I mean it works:

```
>>> dict = {"path": "/var/blah"}
>>> curr = "1.1"
>>> prev = "1.0"
>>> path = dict['path']
>>> str = "path: %(path)s curr: %(curr)s prev: %(prev)s" % locals()
>>> str
'path: /var/blah curr: 1.1 prev: 1.0'
```

I just don't know if you consider that shorter.

Comment: Avoid uses of locals() & globals() :(

Comment: @dzen Why avoid locals()? I've tried searching for this advice elsewhere and I'm not finding much.

Comment: Using `locals()` means that it is not clear which variables you are actually. If you wanted to pylint your code, pylint might well report that some variables were not used even though you referenced them implicitly with `locals()`. Pylint would have to examine all you string format statements for such implicit use. So it is a shortcut whose implications you should understand before using.

Comment: In case the template string is user input, you don't want them to be able to see local variables, in case there are passwords or something. Also "explicit is better than implicit" according to pep20 (don't follow pep blindly, but maybe in this case it works).

Answer (score 8):

You can also (soon) use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) in Python 3.6, which is probably the shortest way to format a string:

```
print(f'path: {path} curr: {curr} prev: {prev}')
```

And even put all your data inside a dict:

```
d = {"path": path, "curr": curr, "prev": prev}
print(f'path: {d["path"]} curr: {d["curr"]} prev: {d["prev"]}')
```

Comment: In python3 print is a function, which requires parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following if you place your data inside a dictionary:

```
data = {"path": "/var/blah","curr": "1.1","prev": "1.0"}

"{0}: {path}, {1}: {curr}, {2}: {prev}".format(*data, **data)
```

Comment: This is the best one.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2016: As of [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew-fstrings) you can  substitute variables into strings by name:

```
>>> origin = "London"
>>> destination = "Paris"
>>> f"from {origin} to {destination}"
'from London to Paris'
```

Note the `f"` prefix. If you try this in Python 3.5 or earlier, you'll get a `SyntaxError`.

See https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add the unchanging variables to your dictionary each time, you can reference both the variables and the dictionary keys using format:

`str = "path {path} curr: {curr} prev: {prev}".format(curr=curr, prev=prev, **dict)`

It might be bad form logically, but it makes things more modular expecting curr and prev to be mostly static and the dictionary to update.